# Simple Login Application in WebForms C#.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone please help me ..I have created a simple login web application in C#.NET and SQL Server with backend db. I Just want to know how to restrict the user if he enters incorrect password more than 3 times . I want to restrict that user for 10 mins and he can try again. So  can anyone please post me detail code how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Restrict the user *how*?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Membership API, to limit the amount of failed attempts and the time window you need to set this in your web.config, like this:

```xml
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: @LukeWoodward thanks for the edit, I didn't know you could have the syntax highlighted like that for different languages.

Answer (score 1):

[passwordAttemptWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.passwordattemptwindow.aspx) in your web.config will do it
also set the maxInvalidPasswordAttempt equal to 3